# psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed

Tags: python, django

I am using psycopg2 to access a postgresql database in a django project. When executing a function that takes around 30 minutes and then saving the results into database 
the following exception appears

```
self.connection.autocommit = autocommit Internal Server Error:
/dashboard/ajax/playbookRunner/39 Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 238, in _set_autocommit
self.connection.autocommit = autocommit psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

any ideas?

Django==2.1.5, psycopg2==2.7.7 psycopg2-binary==2.7.7, and psql (PostgreSQL) version is 10.6

Comment: share some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deployment with WSGI solved the problem here's the link for the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/

Answer (score 0):

sadly it happens in django version 1.3 and 1.4. Please check your postgres log for any detailed information. **Upgrading django to recent version is recommended**. 
Please post your django and postgres version.

Comment: Django==2.1.5, psycopg2==2.7.7
psycopg2-binary==2.7.7, and psql (PostgreSQL)  version is 10.6